# using rsync to 'complete' target

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync` to copy folders/files from my laptop(source) to my desktop(target). I want the files created in desktop to be left intact, but only copy/update/delete to happen on the files created with the laptop.

The `--delete` option deletes files not on desktop(target).

Is it possible to achieve this via rsync?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. How will `rsync` know where the files were created?

Answer (score 1):

So you file to just rsync one folder which updates as you update those files?

```
  rsync options source destination
```

If running from laptop

```
rsync -avz /stuff/ user@desktop ip:/home/laptop/stuff/
```

Or if running from desktop

```
rsync -avz username@latopip /stuff/ /home/laptop/stuff/
```